# Table Header group not working with css transform in print

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to print a table with more than 10 columns. So i have tried to manage to rotate the headers of table to vertical position. Now i have to print this table and i want to get rotated header in all the pages. when i print the table for the first page i can see the vertical headers but it is not followed by other pages (only first page is rendering table headers).

I have created a sample on jsfiddle

```
th.rotate {
  /* Something you can count on */
  height: 140px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

th.rotate > div {
  transform: 
    /* Magic Numbers */
    translate(25px, 51px);
    /* 45 is really 360 - 45 */
    -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
        -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
        transform:rotate(-90deg);
  width: 40px;
}
th.rotate > div > span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

Can someone able to help me what i am missing in this?

[Sample Code](https://jsfiddle.net/vishnu1986/035swam2/3/)

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Because it needs repeating that generate the header by itself, so that please add these into your css.

> PS: if you print at chrome, it will not have any effect becuase chrome is not support this

```
thead {display: table-header-group;}
tfoot {display: table-header-group;}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Jimmy. Is there any alternative solution for this problem in chrome.

Comment: I don't think so, because the browser is not support this

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got one css which works in chrome.

```
.vertical {
        white-space: nowrap;
        -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
        -moz-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
        -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
        -ms-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
        writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    }

<th ><div><span class="vertical">Column header</span></div><th>
```